# replace substrings in list

Tags: python, list

I am looking forward to get rid of a space that is after each element in my list:

```
  list1 = ['Aena', 'Cellnex Telecom', 'Amadeus', 'Abertis']
```

in order to obtain the list like this:

```
  list1 = ['Aena','Cellnex Telecom','Amadeus','Abertis']
```

I have tried the following loop but returns the same initial list:

```
new_list = [stocks.replace(" ","") for stocks in list1]
```

and

```
new_list = [stocks.replace(", '",",'") for stocks in list1]

print(new_list)
```

Could anyone help me to obtain the desired list without the spaces?

Comment: I think you have to understand, that `print(..)` prints the *representation* of a list. With the list comprehension, you alter the elements themselves. Afaik you can't do much about how print prints the list itself. But you can write your own print method.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, very clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to understand, that `print(..)` prints the *representation* of a list (which is a *comma separated list surrounded by square brackets*).

With the list comprehension, you alter the *elements* themselves. As far as I know you can't do much about how print prints the list itself. But you can write your own print method.

We can do this by using a `join` on the `repr(..)` of the elements, and surround it by square brackets, like:

```
print('[{}]'.format(','.join(repr(x) for x in list1)))
```

This prints:

```
>>> print('[{}]'.format(','.join(repr(x) for x in list1)))
['Aena','Cellnex Telecom','Amadeus','Abertis']
```

Comment: completely identical expressions. what are the odds ?

Comment: @Uriel: I just wanted to say the same :)

Comment: btw. great answers both!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> print('[{}]'.format(','.join(repr(x) for x in list1)))
['Aena','Cellnex Telecom','Amadeus','Abertis']
```